# How to convert a KML into geoJSON within a EE-script?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am struggeling with the logic of EE. I want to export an image (median of NDVI) to my google drive. However, the region for which I want to cut out the image has to be in geoJSON format. Yet, I cannot upload this format to a Fusion Table nor can I convert it within the scripting language of the playground.

I tried already this:

```
new polygon = myPolygon.togeoJSON()
```

but it did not work.

if anybody could help ?

here is the link to my playground

https://ee-api.appspot.com/7260e67a9f12397015b971f5bf6a9467

if you try the download in the Task tab you will also find that the download will never stop...any ideas why?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have already figured it out, with the question being asked more than a year ago.

The task never finishes, because you're trying to download the global NDVI image, not the clipped one ...

Best